# Find the predicted probabilities for logistic/LASSO using caret package in R (using cross validation)

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret

I fitted a lasso logistic regression model using caret package in R. My code as follows,

```
require(ISLR)
require(caret)
set.seed(123)
fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv",number = 5,savePredictions = T,classProbs=TRUE)
mod_fitg <- train(Direction ~ Lag1 + Lag2 + Lag3 + Lag4 + Volume,
                  data=Smarket[1:100,], method = "glmnet", 
                  trControl = fitControl,
                  tuneGrid=expand.grid(
                    .alpha=1,
                    .lambda=10^seq(-5, 5, length =2)),
                  family="binomial")
```

When i extract the predicted values, it will only show the predicted class (under the column pred) as follows,

```
mod_fitg$pred
```

[image]

Is there a way to extract the predicted probabilities instead of the predicted class ?  Somehow i needed to obtain the predicted probabilities based on cross validation.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I believe your predicted probabilities are there under the `Down` and `Up` columns. The model gives many observations an even chance and seems to defer to `Up` in such cases. However, there is variation further down the list. `mod_fit$pred` is a data frame and you can just extract the values directly:

```
pre_prob <- mod_fitg$pred[3:5]
pre_prob

#output- keeping index if we care about a certain observation 
    rowIndex      Down        Up
1          4 0.5000000 0.5000000
2          8 0.5000000 0.5000000
```